# c# data from datagrid to textbox?

Tags: c#

I am creating a program that holds customers details and sends them an email alerting them of special offers. I am having trouble when I export the email data as I want to store it in the `sendto.text` field separating each address with a comma, How can I get the data from each row of the `datagrid` and can it be stored and separated with a comma in a `textfield`?.

Hope this makes sense. Thanks

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    sendto.text = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Don;t you mean sendto.text += .... with sendto.text = string.Empty before the loop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this?:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    sendto.text += dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value.ToString() + (i < (dataGridView1.Rows.Count-1) ? "," : "");
}
```

Comment: it creates the comma at the end of last email id.

Comment: I edited the post if the comma at the end is a problem. So no comma at the end anymore ;)

Comment: Exactly like that. I knew it would be something silly but i just couldn't get my head around it. Thanks for all the replies. Wouldn't know what to do without this site. You guys are a credit.

Answer (score 3):

you can add comma from second emailid onwards.

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    if(i>0)
        sendto.text +=","+ dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value.ToString());
    else
        sendto.text = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Also will need to strip the leading comma after the loop completes.

Comment: no need , as i'm adding comma from second mail onwards.if there is only one mail there will be no comma added.

Answer (score 3):

```
   StringBuilder stremail = new StringBuilder();

   for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        stremail.Append(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value.ToString() + ",");
    }

    int stringWithoutLastComma = --stremail.Length;
    sendto.text = stremail.ToString(0,stringWithoutLastComma);
```

Comment: Clever, a little cryptic no?  Consider making `strTo.Length--` a named variable to explain its purpose.

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey I am sorry i think i didn't get your suggestion about `strTo.Length-- a named variable` can you please tell me  ?

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey Thanks now it's became descriptive! Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

You can:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    sendto.text += string.Format("{0},", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value.ToString());
}
```